Dates comparison between two datasets
suppose to have two datasets:
data DB1;
  input ID :$20.Reference_date :date9. Discharge :date9.;
  format Reference_date Discharge date9.;
cards;
0001  14JUN2017  19JUN2017 
0002  12MAR2016  17MAR2016  
0003  01MAY2016  05MAY2016  
0004  19MAR2017  22MAR2017
0005  10MAR2017  22MAR2017 
0007  10OCT2015  14OCT2015  
;


data DB2;
  input ID :$20.Discharge_new :date9.;
  format Discharge_new date9.;
cards;
0001 21JUN2017
0002 13MAR2016
0003 04MAY2016
0004 19MAR2017
0005 22MAR2017
0006 27JUN2022
0007 18OCT2015
;


Is there a way to check if, for each ID, the discharge_new from DB2 is in the interval of Reference_date-Discharge (>=; <=) of DB1? If yes add a Flag = 1 (otherwise Flag = 0) to DB2 to get DB3. Note that there are some IDs in DB2 not present in DB1 that should remain missing. I don't know how to deal with dates comparison from two different datasets.
Thank you in advance.
Desired output:

data DB3;
  input ID :$20.Discharge_new :date9. Flag :$20.;
  format Discharge_new date9.;
cards;
0001 21JUN2017   0
0002 13MAR2016   1
0003 04MAY2016   1
0004 19MAR2017   1
0005 22MAR2017   1
0006 27JUN2022   .
0007 18OCT2015   0
;



SQL is always good for these types of comparisons.
proc sql;
create table want as
select t2.id, 
        t2.discharge_new, 
        case when (not missing(t1.id) and discharge_new between reference_date and discharge) then 1
             when not missing(t1.id) then 0 
             else . 
        end as flag
from db1 as t1 
right join db2 as t2
on t1.id = t2.id;
quit;


This assumes your data are sorted by ID and there are no duplicate IDs (both of which are true in your sample data).
Use the (in =  ) data set option on the merge to create a check that the row is present in the relevant data set.
data db3;
    merge db1 (in = indb1) db2 (in = indb2);
    by id;
    * only keep rows from db2;
    if indb2; 
    * only assign a flag of 1 or 0 if there is a match in db1;
    if indb1 then do;
        if discharge_new <= reference_date <= discharge then flag = 1;
        else flag = 0;
    end;
    keep id discharge_new flag;
run;

